# Line sided heading - how to remove unwanted horizontal space caused by long words wrapping

Tags: html, css

I need to have lines centered at both sides of a text. It works great on wider screen, but problem occurs on mobile, because words are wrapping, and it creates additional space making lines way to distant to text.

```css
  .container{
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .heading{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .heading:before,
    .heading:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 28px;
        height: 1px;
        top: 50%;
        background-color: #0feb9e;
    }
    
    .heading:before {
        right: -50px;
    }
    
    .heading:after {
        left: -50px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
        <h1 class="heading">Some large text lojoijoijoijohygu</h1>
      </div>
```

How to make text wrap as in **display: inline** property, but at the same time preserve height of an element ?? Any other workaround would be fine too,  but I can't affect container too much.

Comment: please put in a code snippet so that we can see the problem in action.

Comment: Done, problem occurs when resizing and when word wrapping starts.

Comment: @norbidrak Is the text supposed to be over an image ?

Comment: @Kangouroops There is background-image in a top parent container..

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want to do with that HTML.  The block of text that wraps is as wide as its parent.